# Read tuple from text-file and plot to graph

Tags: r, text-files, factors

I have a textfile with tuples of integer data, which I want to plot in a simple graph.
The textfile ("test.txt") looks like this. All tuples are separated by tabs.

**Textfile (test.txt)**

```
(1,2)        (1,3)         (2,8)       (3,12)       (5,82)       (...)
```

**R-Code**

```
m = read.table('test.txt', header = FALSE, sep='\t')
plot(log(m[,1]), log(m[,2]))
```

As a result I'm getting

```
Error in Math.factor(m[,1]): 'log' not meaningful for factors
```

What I can understand is, that my data-tuples are not read in as numeric values but as factors. Accordingly the 'log'-operator is not able to operate on these (factor-)values. 
So my idea has been to convert factors to numeric, but I'm failing in converting the data. Furthermore I'm not sure if this is the solution for my problem.

What I would like to have is a 2d-graph with (x,y)-values as axis.

Maybe someone has an idea how to handle it.

--- EDIT ---

```
library(readtext)
library(ggplot2)


DATA_DIR <- system.file("extdata/", package = "readtext")

mytab = readtext(paste0(DATA_DIR, "/hlra/*"))
# readtext object consisting of 1 document and 0 docvars.
# # data.frame [1 x 2]
# doc_id                text               
# <chr>                 <chr>              
#   1 sample_tuple_file.txt "\"(1,2), (1,\"..."
mytuple = strsplit(mytab$text, ', ')
mytuple = mytuple[[1]]

substring(mytuple[1], 2, 2) # get x value
substring(mytuple[1], 4, 4) # get y value 

x = c()
y = c()

for (i in 1:length(mytuple)){
   my_x = substring(mytuple[i], 2, 2)
   my_y = substring(mytuple[i], 4, 4)
   x <- c(x, my_x)
   y <- c(y, my_y)
   rm(my_x)
   rm(my_y)
}

mydata = data.frame(x = x, y = y)

ggplot(data = mydata, aes(x = x, y = y)) + 
geom_point()
```

So, I've tested the Code above. But it's not working for all datas. The resulting plot just the first value. I've reorganised my text-file, so every single tuple ends with a comma and tab.

[plot from code above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PjOkg.png)

I'm completly new to R so I'm sure I'm missing some obviously mistakes in my code. By the way I had to change some code to get it run in R-Studio (added missing library (ggplot2 and readtext) and change file-directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have this kind of text file:

```
(1,2)        (1,3)         (2,8)       (3,12)       (5,82)       (...)
```

I recommend using `read_text`. Work out with vectors and strings to prepare data in the format that's ready for plotting.

```
#if packages aren't yet included in R import them by using R-console
#Command: install.packages("package-name")
#import library "readtext" 
library(readtext)
#install library "ggplot2"
library(ggplot2)

#get directory from "readtext"-package which is in my case...
#C:\Users\your_name\Documents\R\win-library\3.5\readtext\extdata\your_folder\
DATA_DIR <- system.file("extdata/", package = "readtext")

#the textfile you want to plot should be in folder "your_folder"
mytab = readtext(paste0(DATA_DIR, "your_folder/*")
# readtext object consisting of 1 document and 0 docvars.
# # data.frame [1 x 2]
# doc_id                text               
# <chr>                 <chr>              
#   1 sample_tuple_file.txt "\"(1,2), (1,\"..."

mytuple = strsplit(mytab$text, '\t')
mytuple = mytuple[[1]]

substring(mytuple[1], 2, 2) # get x value
substring(mytuple[1], 4, 4) # get y value 

x = c()
y = c()

for (i in 1:length(mytuple)){
  my_x = substring(mytuple[i], 2, 2)
  my_y = substring(mytuple[i], 4, 4)
  x <- c(x, my_x)
  y <- c(y, my_y)
  rm(my_x)
  rm(my_y)
}

mydata = data.frame(x = x, y = y)

ggplot(data = mydata, aes(x = x, y = y)) + 
  geom_point()
```

[image]

Comment: Code is not working for me. Not sure if I'm making any mistakes. See my edited question on top

Comment: The input structure may be slightly different. How about trying ``mytuple = strsplit(mytab$text, '        ')``?

Comment: `mytuple = strsplit(mytab$text, '\t')` worked perfectly. Make sense to me after rethinking my input structure with tuples seperated by tabs ('\t').